# How to play Mov extension ios video in android videoView

Tags: android

I can run .mp4 and .3gp video but i cant play .Mov file when i send video from ios 
those video can't play in android video view

```
 void playFunction(){
         //this is play video function          
         String path = "";

                     VideoView mVideoView;
                     EditText mEditText;
                    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
                    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
                    if (path == "") {
                        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
                        Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path" + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        /*
                         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
                         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
                         */
                        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
                        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                        mVideoView.requestFocus();

                        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new 
                    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
                            }
                        });
                    }
        }
```

Comment: List of supported formats in Android are here and MOV is not listed:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: Did exoplayer worked for you to play mov files. I am stuck for couple of hours with this issue? I need to play local .mov file in exoplayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is media player "ExoPlayer" which is develop by google and support all type of video and audio format. This may support .mov files as per your requirement. You can use like following.

Compiling in app level build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
```

You can refer in details regarding this lib: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks exoplayer is running well but it increases size of Apk up to 20 Mb is there any solution for this

Comment: @ChetanShelake I am not much aware about that. But you can try APK Analyser.It is useful tool by android studio to decrease the size of Apk. For reference: https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e

Comment: @ChetanShelake . Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you to get the required solution.

Comment: As of 2021-08-10, I can confirm that Exoplayer does `not` support .mov files, so unfortunately this will not work.